# Modify the size of vectors in VectorPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, vector

I'm trying to plot in the neighborhood of the origin and I can't change the shape and size of the arrows. What I need is to be sure whether or not the solutions are attracted to the line that goes from (0,0,0) to (0,0,1)

```
VectorPlot3D[{{8 (5 - 6 u)^2 Sqrt[1 - u]
     x (Sqrt[u] x (-1 + z) + Sqrt[1 - u] (-1 + 2 x) z)^2 (-z + 
      x (-1 + 3 z)) (x - z - 2 x z + x^2 (-3 + 9 z)), 
   2 (-5 + 6 u) (1 - z) z (Sqrt[u] x (-1 + z) + 
      Sqrt[1 - u] (-1 + 2 x) z) (-z + 
      x (-1 + 3 z)) (-((-5 + 4 u + 4 Sqrt[-((-1 + u) u)]) (-1 + 
           x) x (-1 + z) z) + 
      8 (-5 + 6 u) x (-1 + 3 z) (z - u z + 
         x (Sqrt[-((-1 + u) u)] - (2 - 2 u + 
               Sqrt[-((-1 + u) u)]) z))), -4 Sqrt[1 - u]
     u (-5 + 6 u) (-5 Sqrt[1 - u] + 4 Sqrt[u] + 4 Sqrt[1 - u] u - 
      4 u^(3/2)) (-1 + x) x (-1 + z) z (Sqrt[u] x (-1 + z) + 
      Sqrt[1 - u] (-1 + 2 x) z) (-z + x (-1 + 3 z))}}, {x, 0, 
  0.01}, {z, 0, 0.01}, {u, 0, 1}, VectorPoints -> 5, 
 VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, z, u}].
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Try it with the options ` VectorPoints -> 10,
VectorScaling -> Automatic,
VectorSizes -> 2,
PlotLegends -> Automatic`

Comment: Try VectorMarkers -> "Segment", this will give lines with varying lengths.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to visualize the vector field in the neighborhood of the origin with specific arrow sizes and shapes. You can achieve this by adjusting the `VectorScale` and `VectorStyle` options. Here's how you can modify your `VectorPlot3D` code to control the arrow sizes and shapes:

```
VectorPlot3D[{{8 (5 - 6 u)^2 Sqrt[1 - u]
     x (Sqrt[u] x (-1 + z) + Sqrt[1 - u] (-1 + 2 x) z)^2 (-z + 
      x (-1 + 3 z)) (x - z - 2 x z + x^2 (-3 + 9 z)), 
   2 (-5 + 6 u) (1 - z) z (Sqrt[u] x (-1 + z) + 
      Sqrt[1 - u] (-1 + 2 x) z) (-z + 
      x (-1 + 3 z)) (-((-5 + 4 u + 4 Sqrt[-((-1 + u) u)]) (-1 + 
           x) x (-1 + z) z) + 
      8 (-5 + 6 u) x (-1 + 3 z) (z - u z + 
         x (Sqrt[-((-1 + u) u)] - (2 - 2 u + 
               Sqrt[-((-1 + u) u)]) z))), -4 Sqrt[1 - u]
     u (-5 + 6 u) (-5 Sqrt[1 - u] + 4 Sqrt[u] + 4 Sqrt[1 - u] u - 
      4 u^(3/2)) (-1 + x) x (-1 + z) z (Sqrt[u] x (-1 + z) + 
      Sqrt[1 - u] (-1 + 2 x) z) (-z + x (-1 + 3 z))}}, {x, 0, 
  0.01}, {z, 0, 0.01}, {u, 0, 1},
 VectorPoints -> 5, 
 VectorScale -> {0.01, 0.01, 0.01},  (* Adjust arrow size here *)
 VectorStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0.02]}, {Blue, Arrowheads[0.02]}}
 AxesLabel -> {x, z, u}]
```